# Generalized Nikodym sets

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let me **quote** en.wikipedia about the original Nikodym's example (the definitions above I've written myself just for MO):

*a Nikodym set is a subset of the unit square in $\ \mathbb R ^2\ $ with the complement of Lebesgue measure zero, such that, given any point in the set, there is a straight line that only intersects the set at that point. The existence of a Nikodym set was first proved by Otto Nikodym in 1927.*

End of **quote**. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikodym_set.

In the above example, we can talk about the open square (or else, we may remove the border points of the square from the set and the things would still work). The $\ L\ $ would be the intersections of the straight lines with the open square. This would define a little bit nicer Nikodym set.

I am surprised that the original Nikodym set was provided in $\ (0;1)^2\ $ instead of $\ \mathbb R^2,\ $hence

**Question 1:** Let $\ L\ $ be the set of all straight lines in $\ \mathbb R^2\ $ Does there exist a respective Nikodym set, i.e. $\ A\subseteq \mathbb R^2\ $ such that the complement of $\ A\ $ has measure $0\,$ and
$$ \forall_{x\in A}\exists_{\ell\in L}\quad \ell\cap A=\{x\} $$
**?**

**Question 2:** Does there exist $\ A\ $ as in  *Question 1*  and such that $\ A = \{2\cdot x: x\in A\}\ $ **?**

> *I'll stop now while additional natural questions come to one's mind; some of them after reading the whole quoted en.wikipedia article.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to Question 1 is **yes**. This is a result of Falconer, Corollary 6.6 in

**K. J. Falconer,**
Sets with prescribed projections and Nikodým sets.
*Proc. London Math. Soc.* (3) 53 (1986), no. 1, 48–64.

The result states as follows:

> **Theorem.**
>   Let $1\leq m<n$. Then there exists a set $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with
>   $\mathcal{L}^n(K)=0$, such that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$, there is a $m$-plane $P$ such that $P\cap (\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K)=\{ x\}$.

This answers positively Question 1 with $A=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$.

Comment: Thank you, Piotr, for an extra general answer. My Q2 was initially a bit different -- I asked about a Nykodym set in $\ A\subseteq(-1;1)^2\ $ such that $\ (-1;1)^2\cap B = A,\ $ where $\ B:=\{2\cdot x:x\in A\}.\ $ Answer *Yes* to this modified Q2 could provide *Yes* to Q1.

Comment: * Nikodym (*sorry for my typo*).

Comment: (It seems, Piotr, that you have 2 *typos* -- the last two $\ \mathbb R^n\setminus K\ $ should be simply $\ K,\ $ I guess).

Comment: @WlodAA No typo. I followed Falconer's notation. The set $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ has full measure so in your notation $A=K\setminus\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Nie kijem, to pałką -- then not the last two but the first $\ \mathbb R^n\setminus K\ $ should be simply $\ K;\ $ am I wrong again?

Comment: @WlodAA You are right. There was a typo in Falconer's paper. Dziękuję!

Comment: Piotr, u'r welcome! :)